# CMake: how to exclude a directory for a given build configuration?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, cmake

I have a project under Visual Studio 2008 configured using CMake. For this project I have three build configurations: "debug", "release", "test". All my C++ files are separated in several directories according to their functionality (Model, View, Controller, ...). One directory is called "test" and contain files that are only for the configuration "test".

Hence, what I have to do with CMake is to compile the files that are in all the directories if the configuration is "test", but exclude the directory "test" if the configuration is "debug" or "release".

Comment: Did you tried wrapping `add_subdirectory(test)` with `if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "test")`?

Comment: @arrowdodger. Good idea to switch on CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE. Unfortunately with a multi-configuration generator, this one is not really used by cmake (except when explicitly specified on the command-line to Cmake).

Comment: Do you mean you have three configurations rather than targets?  A target in CMake is a library or exe that you've added via `ADD_LIBRARY`, `ADD_EXECUTABLE`, etc.

Comment: @Fraser Yes in fact it is "configurations"

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not possible at the moment, due to a lack of a property that controls Visual Studio's "Exclude from Build" feature. There is CMake's [EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#prop_dir%3aEXCLUDE_FROM_ALL), but that is probably too coarse for your scenario.

There is [a hack](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2011-April/043733.html) on the CMake mailing list that tries to achieve this, but that is certainly not a pretty solution.

The easiest way is probably to use preprocessor guards for the test sources and only define the respective preprocessor flag for the "test" profile. In your CMakeLists:

```
set_property( DIRECTORY test 
              APPEND PROPERTY COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_TEST DO_THE_TESTS
            )
```

In each source file:

```
#ifdef DO_THE_TESTS
     ...
#endif
```

Comment: Hack is exactly what I would avoid. I'm using one for the moment, but I dislike it. Moreover, the structure that is under definition for my project is supposed to become a corporate approach.

Answer (score 1):

Normally "tests" would be a target or targets rather than a build configuration.

I guess your tests configuration copies most of its settings from either Debug or Release, which means you're either testing release code (and hence losing the ability to debug effectively) or testing debug code (which means you're not really testing the code which you plan to release).

If "tests" is a CMake target, you can build and run this in Debug *or* Release mode.  To do this, I imagine it would be something like:

```
SET(all_files_in_test_dir ...)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(TestAll ${all_files_in_test_dir})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(TestAll ModelLib ViewLib ControllerLib ...)
```

This assumes that the targets comprising Model, View, and Controller are libs which you have previously added using `ADD_LIBRARY(ModelLib ...)` etc.

If you do it this way, another benefit is that with only two configuration types, you should spend less time overall in building the project.

If you really *do* want to leave "tests" as a configuration type, then I think ComicSansMS' answer is the way to go.

Comment: Hi. I need that "test" be seen as a configuration by Visual Studio. But I will see if something is possible following your proposal. Thanks.